# Outlook button to update/delete a record in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, email-template, apex-email-service, salesforce-for-outlook

The use case is - A subscriber (contact) is sent an email regarding a specific product to which he's subscribed to. At the end of the email is "Unsubscribe" button through which he can unsubscribe.

On clicking on the button I'm need to either update a record or delete a record or do both (on different objects)

Is it possible to perform the task without app exchange product and using any simple integration?